# Choppy ProgressBar performance when used in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-progressbar

I recently encountered an issue where the animation of an indeterminate `ProgressBar` used inside of a `ListView` row became choppy. In a nutshell, I have a `ListView` where each row contains a `ProgressBar`.  The animations look great, until I scroll; from then on, at least one of the `ProgressBar` will have a choppy animation.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image: http://imgur.com/EMoRGnJ]

View for the ListView row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Simple custom ArrayAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        list = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

OnCreate() method for the sample Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,15,16,17));
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, data);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Bug logged (contains sample project): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=145569&thanks=145569&ts=1423673226

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the [view holder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) and check the performance.

Create a static ViewHolder class with a progress bar.

```
static class ViewHolder {
  ProgressBar progress;
}
```

and in your `getView()` you get find the view holder from the view only when the `convertView` is null, otherwise take it from the tag holding the viewHolder. This way you are inflating a new view only when the `convertView` is null, otherwise you are using the views stored in your `viewholder` tag.
A simple tutorial can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder).

Comment: In this case, I don't think the view holder pattern will help. Typically, the view holder pattern is used to reduce the number of `findViewById` calls, which can negatively impact performance (generally, for list scrolling performance). In this example, I never call `findViewById`, so using the view holder pattern doesn't seem like it will fix the problem.

Comment: @Eric Farraro you're right. But I'm curious if the RecyclerView behaves the same. Did you test it with a LinearLayoutManager?

Comment: @cybergen, after your suggestion, I tried a simple RecyclerView/LinearLayoutManager as well. It does seem to work much better, and I didn't observe the same glitch in the animation. Seems like the bug might specifically be with ListView/ProgressBar animation.

Answer (score 0):

it is happening for the first time only, if you close and reopen the app, you will not notice it.

Did you check in older versions like kitkat?

And dont create LayoutInflater in the getView(), create once in the constructor and use it in the constuctor